# Which Adobe product/What API for form entry

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle

I have an embedded PDF in a Java-centric web application.

I want to enable users to type data directly into the PDF, and to receive that data on the server side.

What API am I looking for?  LiveCycle might do this, wondering what else might fit the bill.

Comment: Why would you use a PDF for entering data that is then stored on a server? Can't you use some kind of web form to enter and submit the data?

Comment: Needs to also be able to print in a pixel-perfect manner; it's a federal OMB form that should be able to pass OCR if it's printed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to generate PDFs based on database entries, like Crystal Reports or something similar?

A PDF phoning home information just seems...wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow data capture in a PDF you will not necessarily need LiveCycle on the server side, but it will make your life much easier. The module you're looking for is LiveCycle Forms ES2. This provides a host of functionality for stripping info out of dynamic and static PDF (and HTML) forms.

As a cheaper option you can also consider simply embedding a PDF Form (XFA standard) in your client app. This form will have to be designed using the LiveCycle designer tool which is fairly inexpensive. If you want a lot of interactivity inside the PDF itself (for example allowing users to save it offline for later use or to make Acrobat comments) then you'll also need to apply a reader extension credential to the PDF.

Reader extended forms give you another option, i.e. submitting data directly from a PDF form into a SOAP web service.

Comment: I have a corporate shared license of LiveCycle ES2 available; just wasn't sure if that's the best product.  Sounds like it.